# Annotation tips

Tags: python, annotations

Okay so I've annotated almost everything in my code, but I'm struggling slightly with annotating my for loop, I've got all of it except these two lines I just don't know how to explain with it making sense to anyone but me. Would be great if I could get some tips on this!

```
y = {} #
Positions = [] #
for i, word in enumerate (Sentence): #This starts a for look to go through every word within the variable 'Sentence' which is a list.
    if not word in y: #This continues the code below if the word isn't found within the variable 'y'.
        y[word] = (i+1) #This gives the word that wasn't found within the variable 'y' the next unused number plus 1 so that it doesn't confuse those unfamiliar with computer science starting at 0.
    Positions = Positions + [y[word]] #This sets the variable 'Positions' to the variables 'Positions' and '[d[word]]'.
```

Comment: If you find it awkward to comment every line of your program, that's perfectly natural. The vast majority of programs are self-explanatory enough that only a small fraction of lines need to be commented. You're not doing anyone a favor by writing code like `x = x + 1 #add 1 to x`. That just doubles the amount of time it takes to read your program, and it only helps readers that don't know how assignment and arithmetic work. And really, those readers shouldn't be looking at your code anyway, they should be looking at chapter 1 of a Python tutorial.

Comment: "This gives the word that wasn't found within the variable 'y' the next unused number plus 1" -- no, it doesn't give it the next unused number. For example in the sentence "foo foo bar", it assigns the number 1 to "foo", and then when we get to the "bar" the next unused number would be 2, but the code assigns 3.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I actually checked this, and you're wrong. It comes up with 1, 1, 3 because the word 'foo' was assigned 1 so the second 'foo' was also 1, therefore 'bar' is 2.

Comment: if `Sentence` is `['foo', 'foo', 'bar']` then `y` ends up as `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 3}`. Unless I completely misunderstand what you mean by "'bar' is 2" and "next unused number", then I stand by my claim that you're mistaken :-)

Comment: I'm very confused on how you're interpreting this, every word is assigned a number depending on where in the sentence it appears first. So in the sentence ""Ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country" the output would be "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]"

Comment: Fine, but sticking to my example "foo foo bar", when we get to "bar" I would expect "the next unused number" to mean 2, not 3. 1 has been used. 2 has not been used. So the next unused number is 2. Maybe it doesn't matter, since each word gets a different number. It's just the word "next", that to me impllies that the numbers used for the sentence "foo foo bar" should be 1 and 2. Your code uses 1 and 3, and if that's what you want then fine, but personally I wouldn't describe that as "next unused number".

Comment: That's exactly what I've been saying, "foo foo bar" would output "[1, 1, 2]" you said that the word 'bar' would output '3' instead of '2'.

Comment: Please don't do this. Comments are supposed to make the program easier to read, not harder. Try to write your code so that it's self-explanatory with minimal reliance on comments. Comments can be used to explain _what_ a section of code is doing, or _why_ it's doing it, they shouldn't be used to explain _how_ it's doing it, unless you're using a non-obvious algorithm. Also, it's neater to put comments above the line or section of code that they refer to, inline comments tend to make the code look cluttered.

Comment: Please take a look at [Coding Without Comments](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/) by Stack Exchange co-founder, Jeff Atwood. BTW, Python normal variable names should be in all lower-case, capitalized (and CamelCase) names are used for classes. Going against this convention makes your code harder to read for people who are used to the convention.  Please see the official Python style guide, [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @PM2Ring - I'm only doing such stupidly long comments for every line of code because my teacher said that I had to for the assessment, but thanks for the guide on the style, I never actually knew there was a preferred style among the community as I'd only really been doing Python within school so I just stuck to what I knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to comment a variable, then the comment should explain that the variable contains (or to be precise, since the purpose of the code is to populate these variables, our *goal* for what the variable will contain) and/or what it's expected to be used for. Since we don't see this data used for anything, I'll stick to the former:

```
y = {} # dictionary mapping words to the (1-based) index of their first occurrence in the sentence
Positions = [] # list containing, for each position in the sentence, the (1-based) index of the first occurrence of the word at that position.
```

Answer (score 1):

In one you are declaring a dictionary:

```
 y = {} #
```

in another a list:

```
 Positions = [] #
```

Dictionaries store objects with keys. Lists are stacks of elements (position wise).